# Set of java Protobuf objects vs Class objects behave differently

Tags: java, set, protocol-buffers

Creating a set of objects from a generated protobuf class with the same values identifies and removes the duplicate items from the set (Is this because of matching `hashCode()`?). However creating the `Set` with a class having the same members and objects with the same data doesn't remove the duplicate item from the set since it allocates new address to the created object. How does `protobuf` maintain the addresses to the objects it creates and provide the same object when a new object with the same values is created? Can someone please explain why there is this difference in the `Set<>` construction?

Consider the following class called `NodeJava` which is an class defining a node in a network with members `host`,`port`.

```
public class NodeJava {
    private String host;
    private Integer port;

    public NodeJava(String host, Integer port) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
    }
}
```

Now Let's create  `HashSet` of `NodeJava` objects as follows:

```
Set<NodeJava> nodes = new HashSet<>();
nodes.add(new NodeJava("localhost", 12345)); // New address to each of the objects
nodes.add(new NodeJava("localhost", 12346));
nodes.add(new NodeJava("localhost", 12346));
System.out.println(nodes.size());  // 3 is the result
```

Similarly, defining the `NodeJava` as a protocol buffer message and using the resulting java generated class.

```
message NodeProto {
    string host = 1;
    uint32 port = 2;
}
```

We can build an object using the builder pattern as follows:

```
private NodeProto create(String host, Integer port) {
    NodeProto.Builder node = NodeProto.newBuilder();
    node.setHost(host);
    node.setPort(port);
    return node.build();
}
```

Similarly creating a set of these objects results in a different result:

```
Set<NodeProto> nodes = new HashSet<>();
nodes.add(create("localhost", 12345));
nodes.add(create("localhost", 12346));
nodes.add(create("localhost", 12346)); // Same address as older
System.out.println(nodes.size());  // 2 is the result
```

Answer (score 0):

Sets use `equals` (and by extension `hashCode`) to determine whether two objects are the "same". In your `NodeJava` class, you don't implement `equals`, so two objects are equal only if they are the same object (i.e. if `a==b`).

If you look at the code for `NodeProto` that gets generated, it's likely you'll find an implementation of `equals` (and a corresponding implementation of `hashCode`) that takes the values of the fields into account, so even though the second and third instances that you `create` are separate objects, they are considered equal.